# How can I do "hg shelf apply"?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I would like to copy some changes from my Mercurial shelf to my working directory, leaving an unchanged copy in the shelf.

Git would let me do that with `git stash apply`, however I can't see a way to get TortoiseHg to let me do the same.

Is there any way to retrieve to **copy** the changes from the shelf, rather than **move** them?

Comment: Switch to MQ, which have nice GUI in TortoiseHG?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. unshelve command has option `--keep` (see [`hg help shelve`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#shelve))
2. Shelve extension stores shelves in `.hg/shelves`. If you stored named shelf, you can copy file, named as shelf, before `hg unshelve NAME`

Comment: Thanks: that will be the one Hg command I have to drop into the command line for, pending an option within TortoiseHg!

Comment: In fact, TortoiseHg seems to use a separate shelf entirely. The command line and GUI both have shelves that work independently but don't interact.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: @StevePitchers IIRC the THG shelf feature was developed first.

Answer (score 6):

`hg help unshelve`

says that:

```
hg unshelve --keep     keeps shelve after unshelving
```

So I assume this is what you are looking for.